# Related to Probability Density Function

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable. $P(X)$ gives the
>   probability density function of $X$. Let $Y$ be a random variable
>   independent of $X$ and takes values $-1$ to $1$ with $P (Y = 1) =
>  0.5$. Define a new random variable $Z: = XY$.
>
> What is the probability density function of $Z$?

Comment: “Values $-1$ to $1$” do you mean the values $-1$ or $1$? “To” suggests an interval but only one point mass is given (half chance at $1$).

Comment: **HINT** condition on $Y$

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 the way its written i think P(y=-1)=1/2 and P(y=+1)=1/2

Comment: @SakethMalyala I figured. I was trying to prod the OP.

Answer (score 0):

We claim that $Z\sim N(0,1)$. To see this note that compute the cdf of $Z$. Indeed,
$$
P(Z\leq z)=P(Z\leq z, Y=1)+P(Z\leq z, Y=-1)\tag{1}
$$
by the law of total probability. Next we note the set theoretic equalities of the events
$$
(Z\leq z, Y=1)=(X\leq z, Y=1); \quad (Z\leq z, Y=-1)=(-X\leq z,  Y=-1).
$$
Now we use the fact that $-X\sim N(0,1)$ and the independence of $X, Y$ to deduce that
$$
P(Z\leq z, Y=1)=P(X\leq z, Y=1)=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(z);\quad 
$$
and
$$
P(Z\leq z, Y=-1)=P(-X\leq z,  Y=-1)=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(z)
$$
whence by (1), $P(Z\leq z)=\Phi(z)$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal.

Another way to proceed is using characteristic functions. Indeed let $\varphi$ be the c.f of $X$ i.e. $\varphi(t)=Ee^{itX}=\exp(-t^2/2)$. Then
\begin{align}
Ee^{itZ}&=E[e^{itXY}I(Y=1)]+E[e^{itXY}I(Y=-1)]\\
&=E[e^{itX}I(Y=1)]+E[e^{-itX}I(Y=-1)]\\
&=\frac{\varphi(t)+\bar{\varphi(t)}}{2}\\
&=\text{Re}(\varphi)(t)=\varphi(t)
\end{align}
where we used independence in the third equality.

*From this computation we can see that the the following result holds. Let $X$ be a symmetric random variable i.e. $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution. Let $Y$ be a random variable independent of $X$ which takes on the values $-1$ and $1$ with prob $1/2$. Then $Z=XY$ has the same distrbution as $X$.*